# Vim doesn't recognize angular as HTML

Tags: angularjs, vim, syntastic

I understand that vim would not know until told that some file maps to a particular type. Currently my VIM setting fails to recognize my `.ng` file as '.html' hence it reads it like a plain text.

I want to know the global command to enable that.

PS: I think my sytastic plugin is not working for the same reason.

Comment: You might check out possible answers on the vi/vim stackexchange, which is geared toward vi/vim questions: http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put this into your .vimrc

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.ng set filetype=html
```